# Python subtracting with time format

Tags: python

I have a df that looks like this:

```
   Time_Start               CODE    time
0  2018-01-31 16:45:04.263  B76     2018-01-31 16:48:06
1  2018-01-31 16:10:26.000  974     2018-01-31 16:50:06
```

I am subtracting `time` from `Time_Start`. For the second one I get 39:49 which is the expected output but for the first one I get a number like 2.737000 (not what I want).

`Time_Start` is `datetime64[ns]` and `time` is `object`. This is how I am doing the conversion and subtracting:

```
waiting['time'] = pd.to_datetime(waiting['time']) 
waiting['Duration'] = waiting['time'] - waiting['Time_Start']
waiting['Duration'] = waiting['Duration'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[-8:])
```

I am rather new to python so can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and why I am getting the 2 different outputs?
I am using python 2.x.

Full code:

```
query that returns the dataframe
.......



end_time = np_server_date.ix[0]['data'] """current time"""
end_time = end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
waiting['time'] = end_time """it's now the current time"""

waiting['time'] = pd.to_datetime(waiting['time']) 
waiting['Duration'] = waiting['time'] - waiting['Time_Start']
waiting['Duration'] = waiting['Duration'].apply(lambda x: str(x)[-8:])
```

Comment: You're subtracting Time_Start from time, actually. 

 I'm assuming you're looping through these? Please post your code for context.

Comment: No, time it's the current time which it's dynamic because I'm queering the db every 2 minutes and Time_Start it's the time when an event was activated(so it's static). So it's time(curent_time) - Time_Start(when event activated) = duration

Comment: @Matt_G I edited my question with the code

Comment: Could you explain a little about your goal? If you subtract the larger time from the smaller time, you will get a negative number. I assume you want the time difference, correct?

Comment: @Matt_G if the larger time = 2018-01-31 16:48:06 and the smaller time it's  2018-01-31 16:45:04.263 I would like to get the difference in hh:mm:ss like 00:03:02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I think I have enough info to answer your question now.

Right of the bat, you'll need to [create a connection with pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started).

Then, you'll want loop through your result set and then create datetime objects either through the constructor or using strptime() out of your two times.

Then, you'll subtract the datetime objects to get a difference between the times as a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) object.

Then, depending on what you need to do with that information, you can convert it to your format by doing some math.

```
import datetime
import pyodbc

#create connection
with pyodbc.connect(db, password) as cnxn:

    #create cursor
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('YOUR QUERY')

    #loop through results
    while true:

        #use fetchone generator to optimize memory usage
        row = cursor.fetchone()

        #create datetime objects
        start_time = datetime.strptime(row[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        end_time = datetime.strptime(row[2], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        #the following creates a timedelta object
        time_diff = end_time - start_time
            #a couple ways to deal with the result
            #printing time_diff yields Days:Seconds:Microseconds
            #the following yields the difference in seconds
            #difference = time_diff.totalseconds()
            #alternatively, you can get days, seconds, microseconds.
            #either way you have to do some math to convert to hours and 
            #minutes if desired
            #difference = time_diff.days + ":" + time_diff.seconds + ":" 
            #                            + time_diff.microseconds

            #TODO your division to format the seconds how you'd like
            #using divmod, you can get hours, min, second

            m, s = divmod(time_diff.seconds, 60)
            h, m = divmod(m, 60)
            print "%d:%d:%02d:%02d" % (time_diff.days, h, m, s) 

            #TODO whatever you need to do with this information
        if not row:
           break
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt_G. This is very specific.

Comment: Also if someone it's looking for something simpler waiting['Duration'] = (waiting['time'] - waiting['Time_Start']).astype(str).str[7:15] will do the job fine